# How does '一勿' Compound to mean sundial?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

> [Etymology [of 腸]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%98%9C#Etymology)
>
> Ideogrammic compound (會意): [日](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5#Translingual) ‎(“sun”) + [一](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80#Translingual) + [勿](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8B%BF#Translingual)   The rays of the sun.
>
> [ [From chineseetymology.org:](http://www.chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?submitButton1=Etymology&characterInput=%E6%98%9C) ]
> Primitive pictograph 昜. From sun日 (rays) on a sun dial (一勿). Meaning bright.

My research of the etymology of 腸 motivated this question. I know that `一` means one, and that `勿` means 'not' or 'do not' (ie: negation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**「一」and「勿」do not compound to *sundial*.**

---

「昜」was originally a compound of「日」and「丂」.「丂」originally depicted a handle of an axe, now written as「柯」. The compound is supposed to depict *the rising of the sun*.

## <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)456
[合集3393](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=3393&jgwfl=)</kbd>

As the handle was changed into the shape of「丂」, decorative marks were also added, leading on to the current shape.

## <kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
⿸㫃壺叔樊鼎
[集成2679](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2679&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
　<kbd>現代
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

In contrast,「勿」comes from「刀」, with surrounding marks depicting drops of blood, and was the original character of「刎」(*to cut someone's throat*).

## <kbd>商
甲
[image]
[甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)640
[合集28591](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=28591&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
金
[image]
大盂鼎
[集成2837](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2837&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
[郭・老甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・12</kbd>
　
<kbd>篆
[image]
說文解字</kbd>
　<kbd>現代
楷
[image]</kbd>

---

## References:

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

Answer (score 1):

勿 as in "not" is originally a logograph of a signaling flag. It is not the same logograph as the rays depicted in 昜 (which is 日 rì over  yáng).

It is not uncommon for Chinese characters to have merged similar logographs into one single abstract unit, in the latter case 旦 over 勿.

Take for example 易 (yì), which is unrelated to 昜, although its modern components are 日 and 勿. It is derived from the logograph of a chameleon.

Answer (score 0):

http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/extraPhoto/661c-1383730155_photo.jpg

The ideograph on the right is 昜. Have a look of the 漢語多功能字庫:

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=昜](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%98%9C)

You may compare the changes from bronze script, bamboo/silk and others. In my opinion, the saying of "rays on a sun dial" is, well, beyond reasonable imagination :)

Comment: It would be better if you posted the important information from your link here